# Caliburn.micro and a usercontrol click handler

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I have created a very simple user control, an ImageButton

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleApp.Controls.ImageButton"
             Name="ImageButtonControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding ElementName=ImageButtonControl, Path=Image}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=ImageButtonControl, Path=Text}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

With code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SampleApp.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ImageButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
    {
        public ImageButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

        public ImageSource Image
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null)); 
    }
}
```

Now I want to use that in my little sample application like

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Controls"

<controls:ImageButton Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Margin="2"
                              Image="/Images/link.png"
                              Text="DoSomething">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DoSomething" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </controls:ImageButton>
```

If I give it a x:Name, like

```
<controls:ImageButton x:Name="DoSomething"
```

e.g. DoSomething the method `DoSomething` with that name is directly called when the view is shown, i.e. when I active the viewmodel that contains that button, just like I click the Button (if it was a normal button and not a usercontrol, it would work that way), but the button-click handler is never called on clicking.

Now I tried to add an ActionMessage as seen above, but it does not work either...

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no convention configured for your user control type. You could either add a convention via the `ConventionManager` (see http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions), or you could derive your type from `Button` instead.

You could also not use a custom user control and instead just add the image to the `Content` property of the `Button` in your view.

Comment: Yes good idea, I tend to use an attached property to set an image for buttons; this way you don't need to have a derived control to make a templated button, you can just apply a default style to all buttons. The style can contain a template that has a binding to that attached property so the button itself need not know about it - it's quite effective (though if I recall, there are some issues in the designer in VS2010 with binding to attached properties - works fine at runtime though)

Comment: Yes the approach works well, you can also make the attached property generic enough so that it supports other properties that could be templated (e.g. text, border, background etc) so that one attached property can be reused across all button template styles

Comment: Thank you very much, making it a button instead of a usercontrol works well. How can I make generic attached properties? I do not want to add the image to every button because I want more concise XAML.

Comment: @devdigital: Can you tell me please how I can configure a convention for my usercontrol? I found this: `AddElementConvention<ButtonBase>(ButtonBase.ContentProperty, "DataContext", "Click");` and think this causes the behavior that I described. What should that convention I have to make do? I do not want a ViewModel for my button, it should only make my XAML more concise.

Comment: The link above describes how the convention manager works, but in this use case a custom user control isn't the best solution because it doesn't offer the flexibility of an attached property.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please? Or just give me a source where I can read it myself...

Comment: Yes if you can put the image within the Content property of the Button for now, I may have to create the resource myself and get back to you

Comment: some link will suffice (thats what I meant with source), I do not need the whole sourcecode, I just want to understand what the best solution is and why it is...

Comment: http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties would be something to start with